# E_STRICT messages thrown though not set

Tags: php, error-reporting

Since updating my testing server to PHP 5.3.3 (Debian Squeeze) I encountered strange behaviour regarding the error reporting in PHP.

I set error_reporting like this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and checked the setting via

```
echo error_reporting();
```

which echoes `30719`. According to [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) this means "All errors and warnings, as supported, except of level E_STRICT.".

But in the very next line (a class definition `abstract class formInputContainer extends formContainer implements formElementValueable { ... }`) this results in the message:

> Strict (2048): Declaration of formInputContainer::addElement() should be compatible with that of formContainer::addElement()

Why is the E_STRICT message echoed though it's not set? Even changing to E_ALL & ~E_STRICT does not help.

Comment: This might be to assistance; http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php#98414

Comment: @Chris: thanks, maybe I'm suffering from the same behaviour. At first glance this sound like a bug to me as it's not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: You're most welcome! I agree with you, unfortunately I am unable to give you any in-depth information regarding the matter as I just found out about it trying to assist you with your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a custom error handler (set via `set_error_handler()`), you'll have to check the current `error_reporting` level by yourself. A custom error handler gets all error messages:

The [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) says:

> It is important to remember that the standard PHP error handler is completely bypassed for the error types specified by error_types unless the callback function returns FALSE. **`error_reporting()`** settings will have no effect and your error handler will be called regardless - however you are still able to read the current value of error_reporting and act appropriately.

Comment: You're totally right - this is the problem, thanks! This behaviour changed in PHP 5.3, did it? In 5.2 this never was a problem.

Comment: That's odd. Afaik, there have been no such changes. However, *"declaration should be compatible..."* is a "Fatal error" in PHP 5.2 and cannot be caught by a custom error handler. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

The reason you're seeing them even though they are not set, is that these are thrown at compile time (well, parse time).  That means the errors are triggered before your `error_reporting()` call is made.  The real fix is to change the `php.ini` setting to remove `E_STRICT` from the definition.  To make sure you're editing the correct file, check [`phpinfo()`](https://www.php.net/phpinfo).

Comment: +1 But oddly enough, using `error_reporting` in my script with E_ALL will make the strict warnings disappear... (PHP 5.3.3).

Comment: @netcoder: in a file that then calls `require` to load the class, yes.  But if you put that call in a file with the class in it, it won't affect anything...

Comment: That's what I'm saying: actually it does, the class and the `error_reporting` call are in the same file, and I'm not getting any warning, even though I should.

Comment: @Netcoder: it does that for me.  If I put the `error_reporting` call in the same file, the error is still thrown (with php.ini set to report the error)...  Are you sure you're testing on 5.3+?